# How to sync ScrollViews and have Views on top?

Tags: android, view, scrollview

**What I want to achieve:**
[image: print-preview]

(This image should represent the progress of a printer printing images)

**Top part**

The top bar should represent the whole set of jobs fitted on the the screen. The darker block will tell you what is currently visible on the bottom part of the screen. This should be smaller or bigger depending on the total width of the bottom part. The white strip will tell you where the printer is currently printing. and the yellow strips will tell you when the printer has some warnings.

**Bottom part**

On the bottom part you can see the full sized representation of the printing images. Because its full sized it will continue outside the screen borders.  the large white strip is the same as in the top part and tells you how far the printer is. So what it is doing at the that moment.

You are able to scroll both of them and when one scrolls the other needs to scroll as well. But of course if the top one scrolls 1px the bottom one needs to scroll a bit more because the width is larger.

**What I have tried to do so far:**

Because both need to be scrollable in sync I used 2 custom `HorizontalScrollviews`. I modified the `onScrollChanged` so it will apply this effect. the code looks like this:

```
@Override
protected void onScrollChanged(int x, int y, int oldx, int oldy) {
    int newX = (int) ((int) x*multiplier);
    super.onScrollChanged(x, y, oldx, oldy);
    scrollView.scrollBy(newX, y);

}
```

Multiplier is calculated depending on the widths: `widthBottom/WidthTop=multiplier`

But this does not give the desired effect, because when the bottom part is done scrolling the top part is not at the end. I think this has to do with the width of the top part currently it has a fixed size, it needs to reach outside the screen otherwise it does not listen to scrolls (change of the x value). for the top part i tried to use `Views` to create the indicators but i can't move them dynamically.

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/currentPostition"
        android:layout_width="4dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:background="@color/Coconut" />
```

I tried moving them by changing the marginleft. But this made my application crash.

**What I would like to ask:**

1. Are two `HorizontalScrollviews` the best way to fix the problem?
2. What is the best way to calculate the width for the top part dynamically?
3. How should I create the indicators in the top bar, are `Views` the best solution?

If i need to add some more information, or if something is not clear. Ask for it and I will reply as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Get total width of the content in HorizontalScrollviews and divide scrollX by it. 
This will give you fraction value of scrolled position(How much is scrolled).

If you are using a progress bar set your progress as this value.